# Why doesn't jquery submit work properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code works fine in its current state where im using a click event on a button. But if i use a form tag around the input tags in my html code and use jquery's submit method it doesnt give any results. why is that happening? i have to use the form element because i want to be able to search with an enter key insted of clicking on a button

Html:

```
  <body>
  Title: <input type="text" id="title"><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn">
  <p id="results"></p>
  <body>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#btn").on("click", function(){
   var textval = $('#title').val();
   var playListURL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=' + textval + '&format=json&callback=?';
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: playListURL,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
           var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + data.query.search[i].title;
           $("#results").append("<b> <a href='" + url + "' > " + data.query.search[i].title + "</a></b></br> ");
         //console.log(url);
        } 
    },
    error: function (errorMessage) {
    }
   });
   //alert($('#title').val());
  });
 });
```

Comment: Please could you provide the code you use when you put "form tags around the input tags in my html code and use jquery's submit method", alongside your currently displayed code. Thanks.

Comment: you mean something like this https://jsfiddle.net/qa4ps6t0/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line

```
$("#btn").on("click", function(){
```

to this:

```
$("#btn").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
```

Then the form will not submit default way on click